# MissingMethodException C# Sqlite Compact Framework

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I am developing an application using sqlite as the database on my windows ce mobile .When i try to open the connection i get an exception as MissingMethodException. 
I have added the sqlite and interop dll too still i get the message.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace AGDeviceSample
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try {


                SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=agm.sqlite;Version=3;");

                conn.Open();

            }catch(Exception e2){

                MessageBox.Show(" " + e2.Message);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You could use `MessageBox.Show(e2.ToString());` to get more information about the exception. Does your device have Compact Framework 2.0 or 3.5?

Comment: Mine is compact framework 2.0

Comment: "at DeviceApplicationTest1.Form1.button1_Click()\r\nat System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick()\r\nat System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick()\r\nat System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc()\r\nat System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc()\r\nat Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop()\r\nat System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run()\r\nat DeviceApplicationTest1.Program.Main()\r\n"

Comment: It appears that that version of SQLite requires .NET CF 3.5. See http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/System-Data-SQLite-System-MissingMethodException-was-unhandled-td73381.html

Comment: Yes . That was the issue .. Thank you :)

Comment: Is it possible to Run .NET CF 3.5 on visual studio 2005

Comment: I don't know, we use VS 2008 here for .NET CF 2 _and_ 3.5. There were sqlite.net binaries that run on CF2, but I can't find any download location anymore...